# [ANT]Property and Classpathref inherit broken in "foreach"

Tags: ant, foreach

To explain it briefly, here is an example:

In build.xml, local-db.xml is imported. And in local-db.xml, there is a target named "warmup" which calls one target of the third file -- local-gr.xml using  task.

All the common properties and classpath defs are imported and set in build.xml.

in project.properties:

```
dest-dir=./destination
```

in build.xml:

```
<path id="gr-classpath"> ... </path>
<import file="local-db.xml" />
```

in local-db.xml:

```
<ant antfile="local-gr.xml" target="deploy" inheritAll="true" inheritRefs="true" />
```

In local-gr.xml, there are two targets like this:

```
<target name="deploy">
    <tar ....../>
    <foreach list="${list1}" delimiter="," parallel="true" trim="true" param="item" target="deploy-single" />
</target>

<target name="deploy-single">
    something using property ${dest-dir} and path "gr-classpath"
</target>
```

Now here is the problem:

The property ${dest-dir} and path "gr-classpath" can be used in "deploy" because I set inheritAll and inheritRefs, but it can't be used directly in "deploy-single". "inherit" doesn't when the target is called by foreach?

I managed to pass ${dest-dir} to "deploy-single" with the help of the , but I didn't find any way to pass the classpathref "gr-classpath" to "deploy-single".

What I did to work around it was to claim the  again in "deploy-single", but I don't like it at all.

Why this happens? What can I do to make it more elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ant-contrib `foreach` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) doesn't by default propagate all properties and references to it's target.  But it does have `inheritall` and `inheritrefs` attributes that you can use to make that happen.

```
<foreach list="${list1}" delimiter="," parallel="true" trim="true"
         param="item" target="deploy-single"
         inheritall="true" inheritrefs="true"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you Martin! It's a shame for me as I've checked the foreach document before I ask here and learned to write the <param> but I ignored the attribute list!