# How ant works when targets are repeated during runtime

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am a total noob with ant but more or less I have an idea about how it works. I have come across a situation that I fail to understand and I would appreciate any help.
This is going to be a bit long, sorry. I am trying to make it as clear as possible.

I have a set of targets that works like this : I will use "-" as substitute of "depends" :

```
                - B - D - E - E1 - E2 unless property2 - E3 If property3 - E4 unless property4 - E5 - E6
doc-contracts 
                - C - E - E1 - E2 unless property2 - E3 If property3 - E4 unless property4 - E5 - E6
```

Just in case it is a bit confusing, "doc-contracts" depends on B and C and both paths end up calling target E.

This is the code of "doc-contracts" :

```
<target
    name="doc-contracts"
    depends="B,C"
    description="Generates the documentation for contracts and annotations"
>
    <foreach
        target="doc-contracts-single"
        param="doc-contracts-single.file"
        inheritall="true"
    >
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${properties.src.dir}">
                <include name="*/*.csv"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>
    </foreach>
</target>
```

Basically, for each csv it will call the target "doc-contracts-single". "doc-contracts-single" needs a path reference "pathReference" that is set inside target E.

The thing is that, when I run "doc-contracts" I get this output:

```
E6
E5
E4
E2
E1
E
D
B

C

doc-contracts
doc-contracts-single 
        ERROR: Reference pathReference has not been set at runtime, but was found during build file parsing, attempting to resolve. Future versions of Ant may 
        support referencing ids defined in non-executed targets.
doc-contracts-single
        ERROR: Reference pathReference has not been set at runtime, but was found during build file parsing, attempting to resolve. Future versions of Ant may 
        support referencing ids defined in non-executed targets.

END
```

I have 2 questions:

1. As you can see, it only goes through E one time and I don't know why. I can understand that, once the first "branch" (B and all its tree of dependencies) the flow 
   could be interrupted in E2 if property2 is set (which I am pretty sure, it is what is happening). But then the code should at least go through E and E1 again since those 2 
   tasks doesn't have any condition, isn't it?. I have put echoes in all targets and it simply won't go inside targets E and E1. Under my understanding I should be getting this output:

   ```
   E6
   E5
   E4
   E2
   E1
   E
   D
   B  (end of "first branch", which would be B and the chain of targets it generates)

   E1
   E
   C (end of "first branch", which would be B and the chain of targets it generates) 

   doc-contracts
   doc-contracts-single 
           ERROR: Reference pathReference has not been set at runtime, but was found during build file parsing, attempting to resolve. Future versions of Ant may 
       support referencing ids defined in non-executed targets.
   doc-contracts-single
           ERROR: Reference pathReference has not been set at runtime, but was found during build file parsing, attempting to resolve. Future versions of Ant may 
       support referencing ids defined in non-executed targets.
   ... (once for each .csv it finds)

   END
   ```

Is this correct? Am I missunderstanding how ant flow works?

2. As I said before, the error I get when doc-contracts-single is executed is the following:

With ant 1.7 -> Reference pathReference has not been set at runtime, but was found during build file parsing, attempting to resolve. Future versions of Ant may 
    support referencing ids defined in non-executed targets.

With ant 1.9 -> Error as expected from the message in ant 1.7

I have echoed the content of "pathReference" and it looks fine and well defined until target "doc-contracts" calls "doc-contracts-single". Inside "doc-contracts-single"
    the reference is lost. Can anyone explain to me why? I thought that when you set a path reference in your project, it could be used at any point in the rest
    of the project. I can only think about 2 options:

1- Either some part of the script is deleting it's content, and I can't find which line is doing this

or

2- Because "doc-contracts" and "doc-contracts-single" are not related with "depends" (instead, one calls the other), they are in different scopes and the references set with one are not visible
        from the other.

Sorry for such a long post. I have tried my best to explain the problem as clear as possible. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: UPDATE!! : I have found the answer to question nº2: Turns out that the ant-contrib foreach task doesn't by default propagate all properties and references to it's target. I needed to add the property inheritrefs="true" to the loop. Link to related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759750/antproperty-and-classpathref-inherit-broken-in-foreach

Comment: I still have no clue about question nº1